# How to add anti csrf token to the forms (No Anti-CSRF tokens were found in a HTML submission form.)

Tags: forms, 9, csrf

When i was testing my drupal 9 website for security i got the error as
"No Anti-CSRF tokens were found in a HTML submission form."
solution is given as "use anti-CSRF packages such as the OWASP CSRFGuard." but how to use these in drupal forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal's form API [already implements CSRF protection](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/security/writing-secure-code/create-forms-in-a-safe-way-to-avoid-cross-site-request-forgeries). If your form is not using the form API, you should convert it to do so, and you will automatically have the protection you need.

If your form *is* using the form API, and there are no tokens in the markup, then check custom code/templates/etc that might be removing it.

If you're not going to use Drupal's form API, you'll need to approach this as a standard development task, and implement it in the way that makes most sense for the details of your custom form implementation.